# Enforce tags for S3-bucket creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies, aws-billing

I have been trying to create an IAM policy to enforce tagging for S3 resources.
The policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "s3:CreateBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Tag1": "true"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "s3:CreateBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Tag2": "true"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

This condition works for the EC2 and EB, but here it fails with the following message:

[image: error message screenshot]

What is the error here, and what other permissions do I need to enforce tagging for S3 resources?

*Sorry, I saw some questions alike mine, but none really answers my question.*

Answer (score 1):

The [CreateBucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateBucket.html) API doesn't support tags. They have to be added later via [PutBucketTagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketTagging.html).

Consequently, you cannot enforce tags on creation, to the best of my knowledge. You could implement some reactive process, e.g. scan buckets periodically to ensure proper tagging.

Comment: Correct. The `CreateBucket` entry on [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html) does not show `Tags` as an available condition.